# Is there a way to prevent losing metadata when generating a spatial view in ArcSDE 10.1?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-10.2, oracle-dbms

When generating a spatial view in ArcSDE using a script, any previous metadata is dropped when the old view is dropped. Thus, any edits to [metadata on the view](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/40009), are lost.

Is there a way to keep the metadata around, or perhaps add the importing of metadata to view script?

I'm using Oracle as DBMS. ArcSDE 10.1 and ArcGIS for Desktop 10.2.

Comment: What metadata are you talking about?  If it is Geodatabase metadata, you could recreate the view at the SQL level (Create or replace view ...).  You should keep the columns the same, and it may get interesting if you change the view's extent.

Comment: I was talking about adding metadata to the resulting feature class, e.g. VW_Roads (VW = View). When the view is dropped by SQL command, the associated metadata is deleted as well.